# Twilio, how to bridge 2 local number and hang up twilio number

Tags: twilio

I have a node serve using twilio. I can make a call from twilio number to local number. When local number follow the instructions i connect to agent with twiml.dial('xxx'). Next twilio call that number and create the connection but the charge is double because im calling 2 local number from twilio. i want hungup twilio and free the number and resources but keep the connection between the two local number without twilio.

Answer (score 2):

This is how calls are charged with Programmable Voice, there are two call legs with the programmable logic control the two legs in between.

[How Much am I Charged for Call Forwarding with Twilio?](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132367-How-Much-am-I-Charged-for-Call-Forwarding-with-Twilio-)

> Refer to "Example 3: Outbound call, then another outbound call"